# Utilize the Docker for a Spring Boot REST app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I would like to have a basic setup to run a Spring Boot + MySQL REST app with Docker. The app runs itself fine (without Docker). The project structure is provided,

[image]

This is the `pom.xml` file provided.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appoint.manager</groupId>
    <artifactId>Appointment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Appointment</name>
    <description>A project for Appointment Management</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <!--<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>-->

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>springdocker</imageName>
                    <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                    <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The `Dockerfile` I use provided,

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD /target/Appointment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Appointment.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /Appointment.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/Appointment.jar"]
```

This is the `docker-compose.yaml` file for the project

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - logvolume01:/var/log

  appointment-mysql:
      container_name: appointment-mysql
      image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Appointment
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testpassword
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      ports:
      - "3307:3307"
      restart: always

volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

The followed the steps to run the app via the Docker,

1. `$ mvn clean package`  This This creates the Appointment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar in the /target directory.
2. Finally, I run the command `$ docker-compose up` I get the error message `[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build.`. The full error stack is provided,

   ```
     $ docker-compose up
   ```

   `appointment-mysql is up-to-date
   Starting appointmentmanager_web_1 ... done
   Attaching to appointment-mysql, appointmentmanager_web_1
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
   appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
   web_1                | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   web_1                | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   web_1                | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   web_1                | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   web_1                | [INFO] Total time: 0.186 s
   web_1                | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-12T19:17:03Z
   web_1                | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   web_1                | [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
   web_1                | [ERROR] 
   web_1                | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   web_1                | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   web_1                | [ERROR] 
   web_1                | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   web_1                | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
   appointmentmanager_web_1 exited with code 1`

This is interesting as I did specify a goal in the `pom.xml` file defined here,

```
 <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<build>
```

Whats the issue here and how do I run the app via Docker properly?

Comment: In a separate question, I get the advice to run the command $ mvn clean package docker:build and (remove the line builds in your docker-compose instead put the line image : yourNameImage:latest to get your last build image`. Whats the `yourNameImage` here? The person advised seems disappeared and not responding. I need to run this via the Docker - please, advise me.

Comment: Try repackaging the JAR so it is executable on command line : `mvn package spring-boot:repackage`. You can also do it automatically on build by using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`in your _pom.xml_ and specifying the `repackage` goal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using maven to run docker-compose wich runs then app, try something like

`docker run --rm -v "$HOME/.m2":/root/.m2 -v "$PWD/":/opt/maven -w=/opt/maven maven:3-jdk-11 mvn clean run`
or some version of that with docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible solutions here:

1.The easiest way is to build the image once the jar is generated:

```
docker build -t yourapp
```

And then in the docker-compose instead of build you need to put:

```
image: yourapp
```

See the next option for further details.

2.Your configuration is similar to [this one in gradle](https://medium.com/@itsromiljain/docker-compose-file-to-run-rest-spring-boot-application-container-and-mysql-container-775f15d21416). It uses gradle to build the image, as you are including in your maven example and then it uses the docker image inside the docker-compose. I did not test myself but it should be something like this:

```
mvn clean package docker:build
```

The docker compose should be (remember that [indentantion matters](https://vsupalov.com/yaml-docker-compose-kubernetes/)):

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: springdocker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - appointment-mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - logvolume01:/var/log
    restart: always
```

What you are doing in your example is to build the Dockerfile again. Above I am using the image created, it depends on the other container and always should be restarted.

3.The second example is taken from [here](https://hellokoding.com/docker-compose-with-spring-boot-mysql-nginx/). In this case you can build the image. The maven plugin to generate the docker image is removed. The build part remains like

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The docker compose then is something similar to this:

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - appointment-mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - logvolume01:/var/log
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run 
    restart: always
```

In this example the important thing is the command part. The Dockerfile should be changed as follows (the java image does not have maven installed):

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8
```

Comment: If you have your source code in GitHub I can help you to get it working if you want